# Beauty salon site in HTML 5

Tags: beginner, html

First time working with html 5 so far. Am I using my markup correctly thus far?
Semantically correct that is?

```
    <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Salon Sociel | Hair-Nails-Unisex</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <section class="logo">
            <h1>Salon Sociel</h1>
            <h3>Hair-Nails-Unisex</h3>
        </section>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- introductory content -->
    <section class="intro">
        <article>
            <header>
                <h3>Welcome to Our Salon Sociel</h3>
            </header>
            <p>

            </p>
        </article>
        <aside>
            <img src="" alt="" width="" height="">
        </aside>
    </section>
    <!-- featured content -->
    <section class="featured">
        <p>featured</p>
    </section>
    <!-- keratin complex -->
    <section class="keratin">
        <p>Keratin</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>footer</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Seems to be fine as per your needs, but if you use any HTML5 validator like https://html5.validator.nu/, it will tell you that every 'section' requires a heading 'h1 - h6' element. Rest seems good.

Comment: thanks, any benefits of adding in those heading, like seo, ect..?

Comment: What kind of `<img>` did you have in mind for the `<aside>`?

Comment: I don't think that there would be any added benefit by adding those headings, it is just a definition validation.

Answer (score 2):

#### `meta`-`charset` should come before `title`

The `meta`-`charset` element would ideally be the first element in `head` ([details about the order in `head`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27581639/1591669)).

So it could be:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Salon Sociel | Hair-Nails-Unisex</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
</head>
```

#### Wrong use of `section` and `h3`

You have:

> ```html
> <section class="logo">
>   <h1>Salon Sociel</h1>
>   <h3>Hair-Nails-Unisex</h3>
> </section>
> ```

Neither is the `section` correct here (it only contains headings, and by using it the `h1` is no longer the heading of the `body`), nor is it correct to use a heading element for a subheading ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22451639/1591669)).

So it should simply be:

```html
<h1>Salon Sociel</h1>
<p>Hair-Nails-Unisex</p>
```

(Your structure would have been correct if using `hgroup` instead of `section`, but this element was removed from W3C’s HTML.)

Answer (score -1):

Looks good. The w3c validator errors are just because you use dummy image tags. You should define a heading for each section, but that's just a "warning" not an error.

Answer (score -3):

The [w3c html validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) reports several issues with this HTML.
I suggest to start by clearing those.

Keep re-verifying using the validator until there are no more validations, and your HTML will be in much better shape.

Comment: Your answer before my edit sounded a bit like a lazy offhand remark. With a bit of work it can be rephrased as an advice the OP can follow and learn. Cheers, and welcome to Code Review.

Comment: @janos♦: isn't this a link only answer?